# Using CASE WHEN to insert into a new table with values() clause - Snowflake SQL (classic web interface)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, sql-insert

I'm trying to use insert into() and values() based on an existing condition in my original table to create a new table. I do have working code that uses insert into() along with a select and where clause but I'm trying to see if it's possible to do a **CASE WHEN statement outside of the values so that certain values are inserted into the new table based on a conditional.**

```
-- Creation and inserting values into table invoice_original
create temporary table invoice_original (id integer, price number(12,2),
                                         purpose varchar);
insert into invoice_original (id, price, purpose) values
  (1, 11.11, 'Business'),
  (2, 22.22, 'Personal'),
  (3, 33.33, 'Business'),
  (4, 44.44, 'Personal'),
  (5, 55.55, 'Business');
  
  
--  Creates final empty table invoice_final
create temporary table invoice_final (
  study_number varchar,
  price number(12, 2),
  price_type varchar
);
```

Code:

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  new_price number(12,2);
  new_purpose varchar;
  c1 cursor for select price, purpose from invoice_original;
begin
  for record in c1 do
        new_price := record.price;
        new_purpose := record.purpose;
        
-- This code runs!                
       insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
       select 1, :new_price, 'Dollars'
       where :new_purpose ilike '%Business%';

       insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
       select 2, :new_price, 'Dollars'
       where :new_purpose not like '%Business%';



-- Does not run but this is what I'm trying to do instead  
        CASE  
        WHEN :new_purpose ilike '%Business%' then 
        insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type) 
        values('1', :new_price, 'Dollars')
        ELSE 
        insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type) 
        values('2', :new_price, 'Dollars') END
        
  end for;
end;
$$;
```

This is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do as whole, but just really wondering if a case when insert into() values() is possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INSERT ALL`. Refer [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert-multi-table.html#conditional-multi-table-inserts) for more.

Change code as below

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  new_price number(12,2);
  new_purpose varchar;
  c1 cursor for select price, purpose from invoice_original;
begin
  for record in c1 do
        new_price := record.price;
        new_purpose := record.purpose;

INSERT ALL
when npurpose ilike '%Business%' then
 into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
 values ('1',nprice,'Dollars')
else
 into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
 values('2',nprice,'Dollars')
select :new_price as nprice, :new_purpose as npurpose;

  end for;
end;
$$;
```

Executing above will produce following result -

```
select * from INVOICE_FINAL;
```

| STUDY_NUMBER | PRICE | PRICE_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | Dollars |
| 2 | 22 | Dollars |
| 1 | 33 | Dollars |
| 2 | 44 | Dollars |
| 1 | 56 | Dollars |

Comment: Great this is perfect - thanks so much! Quick follow-up question: I know I can create multiple 'when .... then' statements with the else at the end. I've also been trying to create a 'when...then' statement inside the else clause but getting an error - is this possible to do?

Comment: So it would potentially look like:

when <condition> then
    into table()
    values()
else
        when <another condition> then
            into table()
            values()
        else
             into table()
             values()
select ... ;

Comment: I believe it works like a ```CASE``` rather then ```if-then-else```. And in ```case``` an ```else``` marks end of the construct.
You can include another ```case``` inside ```else``` part though. Similarly for ```INSERT ALL```, you should be able to include another ```INSERT ALL``` inside the ```else``` part.

Comment: One more follow-up - I'm also trying to insert multiple rows but the values syntax ('1', nprice, 'Dollars'), ('Another 1', nprice, 'Dollars') does not seem to be working.How would you go about adding multiple rows in this case?

Comment: Ah I see, I forgot about the INSERT ALL. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [CASE statement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html#searched-case-statements) is allowed as branching construct:

Changes:

a) using INSERT INTO SELECT

b) each statement must end with `;`

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  new_price number(12,2);
  new_purpose varchar;
  c1 cursor for select price, purpose from invoice_original;
begin
  for record in c1 do
        new_price := record.price;
        new_purpose := record.purpose;
           
        CASE  
        WHEN :new_purpose ILIKE'%Business%' THEN
          INSERT INTO invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type) 
          SELECT '1', :new_price, 'Dollars';
        ELSE 
          INSERT INTO invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type) 
          SELECT '2', :new_price, 'Dollars';
        END CASE;
        
  end for;
end;
$$;
```

Disclaimer: Using cursor loop and loop in general should be used when there is no way of rewriting the code to set-based approach.

```
INSERT INTO invoce_final(study_number, price, price_type)
SELECT CASE WHEN purpose ILIKE'%Business%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
       price,
       'Dollars'
FROM invoice_orginal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will write some example code soon.

But the form

INSERT INTO (SELECT FROM VALUES WHERE)

Allows all your N value lines to be present. And the CASE logic to be in the WHERE and the result SUB-SELECT is INSERTed.

The ofther option if you are in Snowflake Scripting is to use an IF around those INSERTS verse using a CASE

What I was meaning, done with "full SQL variables as my example is not part of a loop" is you can move the SQL around like so, and have one block:

```
create temporary table invoice_final (
  study_number varchar,
  price number(12, 2),
  price_type varchar
);
 
set new_purpose = 'Business';
set new_price = 10.0::number(12, 2);
 
insert into invoice_final(study_number, price, price_type)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM VALUES 
        ('1', $new_price, 'Dollars'),
        ('2', $new_price, 'Dollars')
WHERE CASE WHEN $new_purpose ilike '%Business%' then '1' ELSE '2' END = column1;
```

Thus for you loop, the three `$` would be replaced with `:`, but this inserts just one row.

the IF was meaning are the [Snowflake Scripting IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html#if-statements), but there is examples of using CASE just below that also.

Comment: I get that in essence they are the same thing, but was hoping to see if there is a CASE WHEN or even an IFF() solution to doing this same conditional filtering. I've tried doing an IFF() as well instead of using CASE WHEN but I'm getting the same error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 24 at position 11 unexpected '('. syntax error line 24 at position 25 unexpected 'ilike'. syntax error line 25 at position 37 unexpected '('.

Comment: I was suggesting a IF inside the dynamic SQL not an inline IFF, but Pankaj's and Lukasz's answer went where I did not have the time, so you should follow their guidance.